# Install apk tool on Alpine Linux

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

I'm fiddling with a Docker image, built from a Virtualbox VM using Packer. The image is Alpine Linux 5.3.0, but `apk` seems to have been removed.

How can I reinstall `apk`, or build it from source? Googling seems only to yield results on people installing packages, or Android apps!

Answer (score 6):

Probably you mean v3.5.0.

The easier way is (if your architecture is x86_64):

```
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/apk-tools-static-2.6.8-r1.apk
```

And then unpack the downloaded file:

```
tar -zxvf apk-tools-static-2.6.8-r1.apk
```

You'll find in the unpacked apk the apk.static file, that you can use to install apk-tools.

More info here:  https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Upgrading_Alpine

Of course, if your architecture is x86, the url is:

```
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86/apk-tools-static-2.6.8-r1.apk
```

Anyway, the package you need is "apk-tools".

Answer (score 5):

One addition to Francesco's answer (since I don't have the reputation to comment yet):

You may need to use the `curl` command with the `-o` flag instead of wget, depending on how your container is configured. (If you get a `wget: command not found` message, that's probably a good fallback.)

===

Edit: Also, it looks from the "packages" page like they may have removed this minor version in favor of 2.6.9:

https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=apk-tools-static&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=

... so the command set I ended up using was more like:

```
curl -o apk-tools-static-2.6.8-r1.apk http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/apk-tools-static-2.6.9-r0.apk
tar -zxvf apk-tools-static-2.6.8-r1.apk
cd sbin
sudo ./apk.static -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main -U --allow-untrusted --initdb add apk-tools-static
sudo apk.static update
sudo ./apk.static -X http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main -U --allow-untrusted add apk-tools
sudo apk update
```

... etc.,.

Usual disclaimer: If you *can* run things without using `sudo`, you really *should* do that. My situation is not your situation. Try everything without `sudo` first.

Comment: wget as it is used is not GNU wget, rather is built-in with busybox. So you don't need to install curl.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly for me